# Cannot find module 'gulp-sass ionic2 Framework

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ubuntu-14.04

When i Try to add Android platform in my first ionic Project 
this error occurs What is the problem here

```
Looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
Cannot find module 'gulp-sass
```

Comment: Try npm install gulp-sass --save. Verify your package.json you must have gulp-sass in it

Comment: The package.json contain gulp-sass

Comment: Try just another npm install maybe delete the folder node_modules before to be sure. It seems to have been an issue while installing node packages.

Comment: When i try this command this is out 
`npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp-sass" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 135
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.10.0 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself. `

Comment: Which version of nodejs and npm do you have ? Maybe you should update

Comment: I use the latest version of node and npm
node v6.6.0
 npm  v3.10.7